# How to get several eternet mac address by python at windows?

Tags: python, windows, macos, nic

I'm trying to get several eternet mac addresses by python.
I tried this python code, and it works to get the first mac address.

```
import getmac
print(getmac.get_mac_address())
```

In my computer, I installed Virtual Box, and it installed 2 virtual eternal adapters. I want to get all mac address lists which include Virtual Box(or Hyper-V) mac address with Python.

I'm using Windows10 x64.
Sincerely Ryan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `netifaces`:

```
import netifaces
iface = netifaces.ifaddresses('YOUR NETWORK INTERFACE NAME')[netifaces.AF_LINK]
print(iface['addr'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import netifaces
for nic in netifaces.interfaces():
    iface = netifaces.ifaddresses(nic)[netifaces.AF_LINK]
    if len(iface[0]['addr']) > 0:
        print("mac address: ", iface[0]['addr'])
```

Thanks, Wasif Hasan.